# Why I can't change production mode for my laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I run this command and I found out that I work in production mode:

```
php artisan env
```

and after I add to my .env this line:

```
APP_ENV=development
```

after I run all this commands

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

and always I get production mode

Comment: Did you set a static value in your [app.config](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/app.php#L29)?

Comment: what i should set to return it to developpement mode?

Comment: No, it should have the same value as the url I added. Or at least `env('APP_ENV')`.

Comment: yes I found it and i change it to this     'env' => env('APP_ENV', 'development'),

Comment: So, does it work now?

Comment: yes thank's a lot :D

Comment: I have added an answer to your question. consider marking this as the solution so other users might find this as well.

Comment: Done friend thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure the value in your [app.config](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/app.php#L29) uses the `env()` function to get the value from the `.env` file.

If not, the recommended value is `env('APP_ENV', 'development')`.